# Regular Expression Match text in brackets

Tags: regex

I want to find localized text that is surrounded in brackets in a string that can look like.

```
{{de:German}{en:English}}, {{de:German2}{en:English2}}
```

So for the above example I would expect to find two! localization strings.

I'm using the following regulare expression.

```
\{\{.+\}\}
```

As the result I only find one text match, but not the expected two matches.
So what I'm doing wrong here?

Expected matches:

```
First match  -> {{de:German}{en:English}}
Second match -> {{de:German2}{en:English2}}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.+` is, by default **greedy**.  It will match as much as it possible can.  Your match is matching the entire line, since the line ends with two closing curly braces.

To make it non-greedy, append a `?`:

```
\{\{.+?\}\}
```

This will work in most regex engines.  Since you did not specify which you were using, I can't be more specific.

Comment: That's great! It's working. Thanks for the answer. I'm going to accept your answer as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

Make it non-greedy:

```
(\{\{.+?\}\})
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/rE6bQ0/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot. @heptadecagram was few seconds faster ;) But I also upvoted your answer, because it helped me very much.

Comment: Yes I know I was few seconds late as I was preparing regex demo to attach in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its because the + operator in regex is "greedy", meaning, it will match as many characters as it can. Try this regex instead:

```
\{\{.+?\}\}
```

For more information about "greediness" and "laziness" in regex,
read:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html

Answer (score 0):

```
({(?:{[^}]*})*})
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/xT7yD8/1